# Android java how to make a edit text transparent but the text still visible?

Tags: java, android

How can i make a EditText box invisiable but the text still visiable

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" android:text="TestttttttttttttttttTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_above="@+id/trait1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginBottom="78dp">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
```

is my code but `android:visibility="invisible"` makes it all invisible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Instead of below code**

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

**use this code**

```
android:background="#00ffffff"
```

Comment: This is not for color, the 00 in the end will make the alpha to nil making textbox transparent.

Comment: android:background="#00000000" <-- i got it:)

Answer (score 4):

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make a view semi-transparent then use this code

```
android:background="#80ffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

try it..
write it on `onCreate();`

```
EditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```